# Can't access port 80 over the public IP

Tags: portforwarding

I have an ubuntu box at a local IP behind an Arris router from my ISP.  I've setup port forwarding on the router for port 80 such that it forwards TCP/UPD to the local IP of the ubuntu box.

However, I cannot telnet using the public IP, and I can't access apache's welcome page on ubuntu via the public IP.  I can telnet to ubunut's local ip from my mac on port 80 and can ssh into it as well.  I have also disabled the firewall on Ubuntu for testing, yet I'm still unable to access ubuntu via the public IP.

I have checked and port 80 is open on the public IP so is 22, but not 21.

Not sure where to go from here.  Any advice?

Sam

Comment: Sounds like something more suitable for server fault

Comment: Is there a firewall enabled on your router?  You may want to try disabling it temporarily.  Also, you could use this tool to test whether the port is open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: I used that tool and the port is open.  I also did disable the firewall temporarily and no luck...

Comment: Did you do the correct Port Forwarding???

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing port forwarding via the Arris router with

```
ISP/WAN PublicIP:80 --> InternalIP:80 Ubuntu/Apache
```

but perhaps you're Ubuntu client has released/updated it's DHCP lease and received a new internal IP and therefore the intended config won't work without keeping the Ubuntus' client internal IP static...